# Using Jmockit with Eclemma

Tags: eclipse, junit, junit4, jmockit, eclemma

I am using Jmockit to junit my code and Eclemma plugin in Eclipse for code coverage.
For some reason I am not abe to get the coverage. Other project which uses PowerMock, Eclemma shows code coverage fine. But with Jmockit there seems to be some problem.

The following is the exception:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:323)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallAgentmain(InstrumentationImpl.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:150)
    at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.redefineMethods(RedefinitionEngine.java:245)
    at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.redefineMethods(RedefinitionEngine.java:239)
    at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.redefineMethods(RedefinitionEngine.java:166)
    at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.setUpStartupMock(RedefinitionEngine.java:132)
    at mockit.internal.startup.JMockitInitialization.setUpInternalStartupMock(JMockitInitialization.java:55)
    at mockit.internal.startup.JMockitInitialization.loadInternalStartupMocksForJUnitIntegration(JMockitInitialization.java:38)
    at mockit.internal.startup.JMockitInitialization.initialize(JMockitInitialization.java:25)
    at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.initialize(Startup.java:68)
    at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.agentmain(Startup.java:62)
    ... 6 more
5 Dec, 2014 6:40:44 PM com.nn.ood.common.props.PropertyReader
WARNING: No configuration file(s) found for application ca and layer be.
Agent failed to start!
Exception in thread "Attach Listener"
```

Comment: After some googling, I found following link (https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/35) which mentions  that there is incompatibility issue between certains versions of Jmockit and Eclemma. but that was in 2012. hasnt this been fixed yet? Any updates??

Comment: It has been fixed. Which versions are you using?

Comment: @Rogério Eclemma - 2.3.2 , Jmockit - 0.999.15, Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2

Comment: You would have to upgrade JMockit to version 1.8, at least.

Comment: @Rogério Thanks!! it works :)
I will post the answer for others to benefit

Comment: Still not working.. I have JMockit 1.14 and Eclemma 2.3.2. I put the jmockit maven dependencies before jUnit too :(

Comment: @VedantKekan yes, make sure you have the latest versions of JMockit and Eclemma and your tests are actually correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following solution worked for me:

1. Upgraded the jmockit version to 1.9. Please note the group id has
   been changed to "org.jmockit" from "com.googlecode.jmockit" since
   version 1.9
2. Ensure you place the jmockit dependency before junit in your pom

The dependencies in pom.xml looks like this:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      </dependency>
```