# JMockit version 1.17 show error NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.runner.Runner?

Tags: maven, junit, jmockit

I was using **JMockit 1.13** in my maven project. Test cases were running fine. But now I updated to **JMockit 1.17**, Now I see error on console when I run test case like this

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.runner.Runner
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

When I change JMockit version to **1.13**, Test cases start running. I am using JUnit version **4.11**.

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>group1</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject1</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>folder</artifactId>
    <name>myproject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit-coverage</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group1</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group1</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject3</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group1</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group1</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject5</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group1</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject6</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group1</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject7</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group1</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject8</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group1</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject9</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
                    <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                    <!-- Enables analysis which takes more memory but finds more bugs. If 
                        you run out of memory, changes the value of the effort element to 'Low'. -->
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                    <!-- Reports all bugs (other values are medium and max) -->
                    <threshold>Low</threshold>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Maven dependency tree

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject 2.1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myproject ---
[INFO] group1:myproject:jar:2.1.0.0
[INFO] +- org.jmockit:jmockit:jar:1.17:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.jmockit:jmockit-coverage:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject1:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.jmockit:jmockit:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.jmockit:jmockit-coverage:jar:0.999.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.postgis:postgis-jdbc:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901.jdbc4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:jar:4.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject2:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.51:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject3:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject4:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject5:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:4.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.3-1100-jdbc41:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject6:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject7:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject8jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  +- group1:myproject9:pom:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.768 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-13T15:56:52+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/124M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Dependency tree after updating all poms:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject1 2.1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myproject1 ---
[INFO] group1:myproject1:jar:2.1.0.0
[INFO] +- org.jmockit:jmockit:jar:1.17:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.jmockit:jmockit-coverage:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject2:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.postgis:postgis-jdbc:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901.jdbc4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:jar:4.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject3:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.51:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject4:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject5:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject6:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:4.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.3-1100-jdbc41:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject7:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject8:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- group1:myproject9:jar:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  +- group1:parent1:pom:2.1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.106 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-14T21:07:14+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/23M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Stack trace when project1 is ran using `mvn test` on termianl. This stack trace is shown multiple times. This stack trace is shown for each file.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.runner.Runner
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Comment: show pom and  result : mvn dependency:tree

Comment: pom is now added in question. Result is posted above the pom.

Comment: Here is maven dependency tree is now posted in question

Comment: I have replace project name in my organisation with project1, project2 and so on and removed group name to remove proprietary code.

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace (with the Caused by... lines)? Appears to be a compatibility problem between the two libraries.

Comment: try add jmockit-coverage in scop test

Comment: I had same issue and this post helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316808/using-jmockit-with-eclemma

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still coming to this thread, another possible cause of this problem is if your unit test Runtime JRE is using a java JRE instead of a java JDK.

[image: RunConfigurations]

If I replace that jdk1.8.0 with jre1.8.0, I get the exact error above.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the problem is right there in the Maven dependency tree: it shows that multiple versions of JMockit are present in the classpath (`org.jmockit:jmockit:jar:1.17`, `org.jmockit:jmockit-coverage:jar:1.11`, `com.googlecode.jmockit:jmockit:jar:1.7`, and `com.googlecode.jmockit:jmockit-coverage:jar:0.999.26`).

Remove the versions older than `1.17`, and if the coverage tool is used as well, make sure it's in the same version as the mocking library.

Comment: I set jmockit and jmockit coverage version to `1.17` in all projects in dependency in pom. Then cleaned all the projects and compiled all the project then ran maven test but it is still showing the same error. Then I reverted all changes now it started showing this error in `1.13` also.

Comment: When I ran cases with arguement in run configuration `-javaagent:/root/.m2/repository/org/jmockit/jmockit/1.17/jmockit-1.17.jar` it started working.

Comment: Did you notice that your parent pom (`group1:myproject1`), has a `com.googlecode.jmockit:jmockit:jar:1.7` dependency? Note that Maven dependencies are transitive by default, and that the correct way to specify default versions for dependencies in a parent pom is to put them under `dependencyManagement`; in short, your pom.xml and parent pom.xml files contain mistakes.

Comment: I have corrected jmockit versions in all poms which are in dependencies in the myproject1.

Comment: Ok, but did that fix the `NoClassDefFoundError`? If not, could you show again the Maven dependency tree, reflecting the modified pom.xml files?

Comment: That did not work. I have undone all that changes. After that when I added javaagent in argument it was working. Should I again change the all poms?

Comment: It seems your parent pom is still wrong. If you could post its contents in the question, it would help.

Comment: Dependency treed after updating all pom files is posted in question.

Comment: Thanks. There's only jmockit 1.17 now, as expected. So now the question is: what do you get from running "maven test" on the child pom.xml (`artifactId` of "folder")? (Note the stack trace posted in the question was from a Eclipse test run, not from Maven - but we need to run it from Maven first.)

Comment: When I run maven test on eclipse and also on terminal ,it shows the same error for all test classes in project1.

Comment: On Windows 7 I ran my project1 It was running perfectly, It was not showing these type of errors.

Comment: Could you show the stack trace from the failing test, as produced by running the Maven "test" goal?

Comment: The stack trace is same that is posted above. That stack trace is shown multiple times when I run the project1, Because it is shown for each test class. When I run the project after setting `javaagent` in `VM arguments` it runs perfectly.

Comment: But that stack trace, as I said before, *is from Eclipse*; you need to run the tests with Maven, by executing the "`maven test`" command. Eclipse has its own JUnit integration, and it uses a separate build path configuration, from which it assembles the runtime classpath used for a test run; this classpath can be different from the classpath that Maven would produce.

Comment: It was showing the same stack trace as eclipse when ran on terminal in linux.

Comment: The Maven Surefire plugin, which executes the test suite when running `maven test`, is independent of any `org.eclipse.jdt` classes. So, there is no way for such Eclipse-specific classes to appear in the stack trace.

Comment: Thank you. The stack trace was different , Only first two lines were same as eclipse stack trace. Question is updated with trace of terminal.

Comment: On other linux machine test cases are running perfectly with different JMockit versions in maven dependency tree.

Comment: Ok. The `NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.runner.Runner` occurs because something is causing JMockit initialization to fail. This initialization code is in class `mockit.internal.startup.Startup` (it's called from the static initializer of a modified `org.junit.runner.Runner` class - the static initialization failure then causes the NoClassDefFoundError, it's normal JVM behavior). The stack trace for any throwable should have being printed to standard output, so maybe it shows in Maven output somewhere? If not, I would set a breakpoint there and debug it to find the root cause for the failure.